# Google Drive API: AttributeError: 'Credentials' object has no attribute 'request'

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api

I am adding google drive sync feature to my GUI, where user can upload some important folders to drive, after some time for backup, i followed the code by google drive api, but it is giving me error, i searched almost all related questions, but none seem to resemble with my case.

he is the full traceback:

```
File "D:\Programming Projects\Projects-Manager\main.py", line 96, in <module>
    id_ = upload_zip(zip_created_path, cred_path)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    

File "D:\Programming Projects\Projects-Manager\google_drive\drive.py", line 51, in upload_zip
    fields='id').execute()
                 ^^^^^^^^^
    

  File "D:\Programming Projects\Projects-Manager\env\Lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


  File "D:\Programming Projects\Projects-Manager\env\Lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 902, in execute
    _, body = self.next_chunk(http=http, num_retries=num_retries)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    


  File "D:\Programming Projects\Projects-Manager\env\Lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "D:\Programming Projects\Projects-Manager\env\Lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 1007, in next_chunk
    resp, content = _retry_request(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "D:\Programming Projects\Projects-Manager\env\Lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 191, in _retry_request
    resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^

AttributeError: 'Credentials' object has no attribute 'request'
```

The code which caused the error:

```
import os.path
from pathlib import Path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload


SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly",
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly"]

drive_folder = "google_drive"

def get_token(cred_path):
    cred_path = Path(cred_path)
    cred = None
    token_file_path = Path(Path.cwd(), drive_folder, "token.json")

    if token_file_path.exists():
        cred = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(str(token_file_path), SCOPES)

    if not cred or not cred.valid:
        if cred and cred.expired and cred.refresh_token:
            cred.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                str(cred_path), SCOPES
            )
            cred = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open(token_file_path, 'w') as file:
            file.write(cred.to_json())
        return cred

    return cred

def upload_zip(zip_created_path, credential_path):
    cred = get_token(credential_path)
    zip_name = os.path.basename(zip_created_path)
    try:
        service = build("drive", 'v3', cred)

        file_metadata = {"name": zip_name, "mimeType": "application/zip"}
        media = MediaFileUpload(zip_created_path, mimetype="application/zip", resumable=True)

        file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media,
                                      fields='id').execute()
        os.remove(zip_created_path)
        return file.get('id')

    except HttpError as error:
        print(F'An error occurred: {error}')
        return
```

Comment: hey @SAVEPALASTINE did Fernando's answer work for you?

Comment: umm actually, my code was same as his, the issue was idk what, but when i limited the scopes, that worked, when i added just 2 scopes that were neccesory, it worked, idk how

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were not using the credentials correctly, therefore you were getting the error message. You can try the following code:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload


# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

def main():
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
    
    reg_uploadb("filename.zip", creds)


def reg_uploadb(zip_created_path, creds):

    zip_name = os.path.basename(zip_created_path)

    try:
        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
        
        
        file={ "name":zip_name, "mimeType":"application/zip"}
        

        media_body = MediaFileUpload(zip_created_path, mimetype='application/zip', resumable=True)
        
        updated_file = service.files().create(
            body = file,
            media_body = media_body
        ).execute()


        print(F'File ID: {updated_file.get("id")}')

    except HttpError as error:
        print(F'An error occurred: {error}')

    return file.get('id')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```